# 2 jquery .click functions for one button . fire functions one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jquery .click functions for one button. functions should fire one after another. Second function not firing.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="70px" />
```

```
// this function is fired 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>).click(function () {
        //some code here
        var con = confirm("message");
        if (con) return true;
        else return false;
    });
});

// in another <script>
// this function is not getting fired
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                var con1 = confirm("message");
                if (con1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
});
```

how can both function fire one after another?? or how can i write both logic in one function?

Comment: Change it to 1 click event that calls the two sets of functionality.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `"` after `"#<%=Button1.ClientID%>`, I didn't add it in with my edit in case that was the cause.

Comment: Does the first "confirm()" function ever return true?   If you return false from that first function, it will probably cancel the second.

Comment: Hey Richard, yes the first function returns True.

Comment: Paul its a typo here. id is ended with " in the code.

Comment: @user2584344 feel free to edit your question if you have made a typo in the code which is unrelated to the problem you're experiencing. Another user also mentioned (idk where the comment went now) that you have one too many `}` in the second _function_.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script>
    var clientId=<%=Button1.ClientID%>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#"+clientId).click(function () {
          var con1 = confirm("message");
          return con1;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that your functions are not getting called one after another. In fact they would have been called if you used the braces `{}` properly.  See my code below(most notably the js part) :

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="70px" >CLICK</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS :**

```
$(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        alert("1");
        var con = "message";
        if (con) return true;
        else return false;
    });
});


// this function is now getting fired
$(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
                alert("2");
                var con1 = "message";
                if (con1) return true;
                 else return false;
            });

});
```

See the working example here : http://jsbin.com/IkIx/1/edit .As usual remember to `run with js` .